# Plot a function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I need to plot the following function in R:

```
M(x) =  2 + 0.4x {when x <= 0} 
       -2 + 0.6x {when x >  0}
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
fx1 = function(x){
  2+0.4*x
}
fx2 = function(x){
  -2-0.6*x
}
plot(fx1, -10,  0)
plot(fx2,   0, 10)
```

But the functions are plotted in two different windows. I've also tried to add: `add=TRUE` to the second plot, which I read on Stack Overflow, but this didn't help me either.

Comment: Every time you call plot, you get a new window. Replace plot(fx2...) with lines(fx2...) and you'll paste a line unto the same plot as is already open.

Check out this link for a little more information on plotting: 
http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/line.html

Comment: If I use lines, I get the following error: Error in as.double(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

I got the add=TRUE to work though, but do you know how to define the intervals correctly, it's only using the interval from the first plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot functions, use `curve`. Use `plot`, to get the coordinates before adding curves:

```
fx1 = function(x){
  2+0.4*x
}
fx2 = function(x){
  -2-0.6*x
}
plot(NA, xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(-10,10))
curve(fx1, from = -10, to = 0, add=TRUE)
curve(fx2, from = 0, to = 10, add=TRUE)
```

**Edit:**
For better definition at x=0, may I suggest

```
fx1 = function(x) 2+0.4*x
fx2 = function(x) -2-0.6*x

plot(NA, xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(-10,5), ylab="value")
curve(fx1, from = -10, to = 0, add=TRUE)
curve(fx2, from = 0, to = 10, add=TRUE)
points(0, fx1(0), pch=15)
points(0, fx2(0), pch=22)
```